# mysql search query which one better

Tags: php, mysql

When doing a search with MySQL, which query is better?

```
SELECT id from table where strcol = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT id from table where strcol = '1'
```

Where `strcol` is a varchar(1) field

Comment: On the assumption that strcol might not be an integer, '1' is better.

Comment: Does your column contains only numeric values?

Comment: currently only have INT value, i know if create this column as numeric datatype is better. But the system is already there, just want to know  which query server better for mySQL

Answer (score 1):

'1' is better option,becaus your strcol has type varchar.

Answer (score 1):

as stated by others already, you should stay with the same data type the column is.
So if you have a varchar, use the quotes to select from it, since otherwise the auto typecasting of mysql would be used. This typecasting might not be too much of a problem with relatively small amount of data, but will definitely be a problem at scale since you won't have any advantages from indexes.

To read about the auto typecasting in mysql please [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html).

The interesting part here for you might be:

> For comparisons of a string column with a number, MySQL cannot use an
>   index on the column to look up the value quickly. If str_col is an
>   indexed string column, the index cannot be used when performing the
>   lookup in the following statement...

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a `varchar`, you should always enclose it in `'` marks - you may be using only numbers in there for now (and it works either way if you do use numbers) but if a letter ever ends up in that column, MySQL will fail to convert it into an `int` and throw an error.

Comment: @Strawberry `Invalid column name 'asdasdasd'.` for example ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the reply

May i know what is reason for me to include ' ? is that a coding standard?
i try it on my localhost with `strcol` is mixed with INT & varchar value
i use SELECT id from table where strcol = 1, mysql still return me the correct result

Comment: @stormaaron you do that so you will always get a result as pointed out in my first comment. If you try to search for a string without encapsulating it in `'`s you will get an error; what you are experiencing is the result of implicit value casting - to be completely precise there is no column that contains values `mixed with INT & varchar` it is a varchar column that happens to contain varchars that can be implicitly cast into ints

Comment: @stormaaron It's part of the MySQL syntax (along with other database systems). It's worth noting that if you only ever plan to use numeric values in there that you change the column to `int` - that way you can then remove the `'` from the query.

Comment: Yea guys, currently the column only contain numeric value. but the system is already there for years. i can't change it suddenly. so i would like to know which query serve MYSQL better. or it did not impact to any mysql performance and just a best practice of coding standard

Comment: @stormaaron sure you can `change it suddenly` ;) just be sure not to do it in your production environment at first, test it in a test environment, as you say it only contains numbers: `1. create a new int column 2. copy all values over from your "old" varchar column 3. drop the old varchar column 4. rename the new column to match the old varchar column's name 5. dont worry about 's in that column anymore ;)`

Answer (score 0):

Just as a rule of thumb, I believe you should stick to data types when executing queries, so I would suggest:

```
SELECT id from table where strcol = '1'
```

Purely because the data type is a varchar

Answer (score 0):

since strcol is of type varchar i suggest:

```
SELECT id from table where strcol = '1'
```

always wrap strings with quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

SInce `strcol` is of a `VARCHAR()` type, Use this instead:

```
SELECT id from table where strcol = '1'
```

The other option can be valid only if `strcol` is  a *numeric* value (int, flot, number ...)